# Does Boost have a GUI library?

Tags: c++, user-interface, boost

I want to work with the Boost library and I was wondering what GUI can I use with it? Is there any GUI library for Boost? And how can I integrate both GUI and Boost to each other?

Thanks your help.

Answer (score 24):

No, Boost has no GUI library. If you need a multiplatform C++ GUI library, then take a look at e.g. [Qt](https://www.qt.io/). There is nothing much to 'integrate' between Boost and a GUI library, though.

Comment: or tray wxWidgets also

Answer (score 18):

Yes, there is boost.ui:

[Boost.UI](https://kosenko.github.io/boost.ui/) is a C++ User Interface (GUI) Boost library:

- This is cross-platform
- Uses native system-provided widgets
- It has STL-like and Boost-like API
- Compatible with other Boost libraries
- Supports modern C++11/14/17 features
- It supports Graphics, various Widgets, Events, Layouts.

You can refer [here for more informations and examples](https://github.com/kosenko/ui).

Comment: That's not actually a part of boost.

Comment: @Ayxan yes, more discussion here: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15359429

Answer (score 14):

No, Boost has no GUI library.

There has been some long discussions on what one should include, but as usual there was no agreement. This is a hard issue!

Answer (score 5):

Might give [Clutter](http://www.clutter-project.org/) a shot.  OpenGL/ES-based.  Pretty much every modern computing device with a screen has some sort of OpenGL support these days.

Comment: try imgui!, it is based on opengl. https://github.com/ocornut/imgui

Answer (score 1):

[SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) might be worth a shot too. It's 'Simple and Fast' Multimedia Library.